# Scheduled builds on CircleCI

Tags: circleci

We currently have a CircleCI pipeline, that get's triggered whenever a commit gets merged to the test environment.

It builds the app and then runs some tests againsts it using the url of the web app. All this is defined in the config.yml file.

e.g.

Step 1 - Builds the app

Step 2 - Runs tests against the app (on https://)

How can one create a nightly build that only runs tests i.e. Step 2?

In this case, it is not triggered by a commit to the test environment, but is just a scheduled build that runs tests at a specified time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CircleCI supports scheduling jobs through the Scheduled Pipelines feature. From the docs

> Scheduled pipelines allow you to trigger pipelines periodically based on a schedule.

You can configure scheduling by choosing your project and then going to `Project Settings -> Triggers -> Add Triggers`.

In the trigger configuration, add a pipeline parameter, `run-tests` for instance, which will be passed to the pipeline when the trigger executes the schedule.

Additionally, add the same pipeline parameter to your config.yaml and a when statement to the workflow you want to run, which will check if the pipeline parameter `run-tests` is present. That should be all the configuration needed to execute a pipeline on a schedule with a specific workflow.

Documentation: https://circleci.com/docs/scheduled-pipelines/